# Cannot print out "event.char" using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I run this successfully in Python 2.7 with Pycharm IDE in one Macbook. I press arrow up key, event.char is not null, it can print out something. However, in the other Macbook or windows system, when I press keys which are not letters, it can not print out anything, all I see is "press: ". When I press letter key,it worked fine, and it print out the letters such like "press : A". Any thought is appreciated.

```
     #
from Tkinter import *
#Entry
def printkey(event):
    print('press:' + event.char)
#
root = Tk()
#input
entry = Entry(root)
#
entry.bind('<Key>', printkey)
#
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `event.keysym`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code,    `event` is a Tkinter event object. This object has a short list of attributes, among them these 2 ones related to keyboard events (only):

- **`char`**: A single-character string that is the key's code
- **`keysym`**: A string that is the key's symbolic name

The later one is apparently what you are looking for.

You will find here [*a list enumerating the keysyms that will be recognized by Tk*](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm).

Other [attributes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/other/python/0596001886_pythonian-chp-16-sect-9.html) of this `event` Tkinter object:

- **`num`**: Button number (only for mouse-button events); 1 and up
- **`x`**, **`y`**: Mouse position, in pixels, relative to the upper left corner of the widget
- **`x_root`** , **`y_root`**: Mouse position, in pixels, relative to the upper left corner of the screen
- **`widget`**: The widget in which the event has occurred.

So your code should now look like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
#Entry
def printkey(event):
    print('press:' + event.keysym)
#
root = Tk()
#input
entry = Entry(root)
#
entry.bind('<Key>', printkey)
#
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

`char` only contains a value when the key pressed corresponds to a character. If it does not then you will need to print or translate one of the other attributes, such as `keysym`.